# ¿Como puedo cambiar los atributos de un elemento despues de un determinado tiempo en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Me gustaria que cuando recorra el array me vaya mostrando por pantalla cada 2 segundos el siguiente valor, pero el problema es que no veo los cambios de forma secuencial, si no que me los hace de golpe.

He probado con el setInterval o setTimeout en el for y no lo consigo, os dejo el codigo:

```
export const drawPath = (path,rowInit,colInit,rowFinish,colFinish) => {
    path.forEach(elem => {   
        setTimeout(function(){
            if((elem.i != rowInit && elem.j != colInit) && (elem.i != rowFinish && elem.j != colFinish)){
                let cellPath = document.getElementById("board1").rows[elem.i].cells[elem.j];
                cellPath.style.backgroundColor= "#dcfaea" 
                cellPath.innerText = "";
                cellPath.style.fontSize = "35px";     
            }
        }, 2000);
   
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que nos compartes, las funciones `setTimeout` se están ejecutando todas de manera secuencial, después de 2 segundos:

```js
let any=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
any.forEach((elem, index) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(`ejecución secuencial ${index} despues de 2000 ms`)
        console.log(index);
    }, 2000);
});
console.log(`Hay ${any.length} funciones en lista de espera`);
```

Como se puede observar en el ejemplo anterior, se estan mandando `any.length` funciones a espera, pero todas configuradas con un retardo de 2 segundos.

Para conseguir el efecto deseado, se tiene que modificar el retardo de forma dinámica, usando el parámetro `index`:

```js
let any=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

any.forEach((elem, index) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(`ejecución secuencial ${index} despues de ${index * 2000/2} ms`)
        console.log(index);
    }, index * 2000);
});
 console.log(`Hay ${any.length} funciones en lista de espera`);
```

Recordemos que `setTimeout` tiene referencia a `index`, entonces cada que `forEach` registra una función `setTimeout`, esta usa la referencia `index` para generar un nuevo retardo y es así, como se logra que cada `setTimeout` quede registrado en memoria con un valor del retardo distinto y en la sincronía deseada, para cada iteración.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo entiendo, y me funciona perfectamente